# Theoretical background of Google Or-tools

Tags: optimization, knapsack-problem, or-tools, vehicle-routing

Currenlty I'm working on my thesis work about Tourism optimization, that contain both Knapsack and VRP solvers from OR-tools. At this point I need some theoretical background about OR-tools.

After internet search I didn't find any information I looked for. My main concerns are:
1. How does it work in a nutshell?(in comparison with other solvers)
2. Is it using any known algorithms as Gradient Decent or other or it developed it's own?
3. What are the key factor making OR-tools faster than other solvers?

I understand that all this information might be confidencial, and that's why there's nothing on internet. I hope for any clarification on this topic and will be grateful for any useful information.

Answer (score 2):

1 and 2) Routing: https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/920. Knapsack is inspired by the by http://www.or.deis.unibo.it/kp/KnapsackProblems.pdf

3) mostly a lot of work :-)

The code is open source. What could be confidential ?